# Don't allow changing document.domain value

Tags: javascript

I need to deny changing `document.domain`. Say, if I run this code at *foo.boo.com*

```
Object.defineProperty(document, 'domain', { 
    get: function () {
        return 'foo.boo.com';
    }
});
```

and then will it be possible to set `document.domain` to *boo.com*? I ask because I want to deny changing `document.domain` by untrusted code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have zero control over this.

Comment: @ceejayoz, over what exactly?

Comment: Over whether or not a browser can set `document.domain`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to prevent? Are you trying to break out of a frame or other situation?

Comment: @ceejayoz, so you mean that if I run the above-mentioned code and after that I run the untrusted code, it is still possible for the untrusted code to change document.domain?

Comment: @Jared Farrish, no. There is some complex situation actually.

Comment: You're better off explaining the situation and seeing what you can do about it than haphazardly "finding" a solution (although you could suggest this *may* work).

Comment: Yeah, knowing the use case would help a lot here. As for whether the untrusted code would be able to change `document.domain`, yes, it would. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code you propose does not appear to work at all. Safari:

[image]

A demonstration of it failing to prevent modification of `document.domain` in Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Seems your browser doesn't support it. Test it in the latest FF.

Comment: This is the latest version of Safari.

Comment: @Jared, replace `console.log` with `alert`, and you'll get the same behavior (except more annoying)

Comment: @Jared, because your previous comment implies this answer has something inherently to do with `console`.  It does not.

Comment: @ceejayoz, you're right it doesn't work. I just changed the code, try it instead.

Comment: @Polar That changed code doesn't work either. Per the error message I've shown, you simply **cannot** run `defineProperty` on `document`.

Comment: The code works in the latest build of Chrome. Use Chrome and stop arguing about browser inconsistencies/incompatibilities...

Comment: @Xander My Chrome states "Google Chrome is up to date (14.0.835.202)". My second screenshot is from that Chrome build. Browser inconstancies/incompatibilities matter **hugely** if you're trying to do something to secure a page and it's not going to work in some browsers.

Comment: @Xander - Unless you know a specific implementation is locked down to a specific browser (and possibly version), your comment isn't really useful to the problem at hand.

Comment: @ceejaoz I ***completely*** agree. I am just curious if it is actually possible to alter the default behavior of the `domain` property on the `document` object.

Comment: As a side note, is the code working in your Chrome, or does it just not throw an error? I don't get the error in Chrome but it doesn't prevent changing of `document.domain`. Safari throws an actual error but both have the same result.